# Message is available even after deleting in Slack channel

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

When I delete a message as Slack Bot, I get success response. But messages still in channel. Below is the python snippet

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
slack_token = "xxxx-32165498765-ASDFWERT651V6541FDG651"
sc = SlackClient(slack_token)
delete = sc.api_call(
  "chat.delete",
  channel="C32S1DFRET",
  ts="1509234662.000060",
  as_user=True
)
```

Comment: Are you using a bit token or user token? Was the message you are trying to delete posted by the same user?

Comment: Also, how are you determining success? An HTTP 200 is not enough, you have to check the response payload. For example, you may be receiving a `cant_delete_message` error.

Comment: It's token that gets generated for bot. Bit token I believe. I'm checking the content of response as well. It had deleted ts and channel and channel ID.

Comment: That was a typo- sorry. I meant bot token, not bit. You can tell if it's a bot token if it starts with `xoxb` instead of `xoxp`.

Comment: Yes. It starts with xoxob.

Comment: And which user posted the message you're trying to delete? The bot or a human user?

Comment: The message that I posted through bot.

Answer (score 0):

If the bot posted the message, that should work.  You will need to check the response payload. I'm guessing there will be an error and that it isn't failing silently. Only the error message will let you know what the issue is for sure.

Is it possible though that you don't have the `chat:write:user` scope?
According to [the docs](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete), to use `as_user` you must have the `chat:write:user` scope. Check if the response contains a 
`cant_delete_message` error.